# Knockout.js to switch languages in a bilingual site

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, client-side

I'm trying to use knockout.js to make my site bilingual. I will have the typical flags that users can click on to switch the language.

The implementation of knockout.js I'm using is this: https://github.com/tfsjohan/Knockout-Localization-Binding

I've modified it quite a bit, as the original was overkill for what I needed.

What I'm trying to do is set up a demo of a set of radio buttons that I can use to simulate switching the language. When I click on a button, I want the text to change to my language of choice.

Here is my JS:

```
var resources = {
pLangSelect: {
    en: 'Select your language:',
    es: 'Selecciona tu idioma:'
},
welcome: {
    en: 'Hello <strong>Christopher</strong>! You live in London.',
    es: 'Hola, ¡<strong>Cristóbal</strong>! Vives en Bogotá.'
}
};
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Knockout Localization Binding Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div data-bind="restext: 'pLangSelect'"></div>
    <labal for="eng">English</labal>
    <input type="radio" id="eng" name="lang-select">
    <labal for="eng">Español</labal>
<input type="radio" id="esp" name="lang-select">
<div data-bind="reshtml: { key: 'welcome' }"></div>
</div>

<script src="resources.js"></script>
<script src="knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="../src/ko.localizationbinding.js"></script>
<script>
    var choice = document.getElementById('esp');
    var locale;

    if (choice.selected) {
        locale="en";
    } else {
        locale="es";
    }

    choice.onclick = function(e) {
        if(choice.checked)
            locale = 'en';
        else
            locale = 'es';
    }

    var vm = {
    name: ko.observable(),
    city: ko.observable()
    };

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks for your help with this matter.

Comment: What's your specific question? BTW, if I were doing this I'd just use separate templates for each language, bringing them in with a variable `name` option on the `template` binding.

Comment: If you want the view to update when you change the locale you need to change it to observable, also the Knockout-Localization-Binding library most be able to utilize this in its bindings

Answer (score 0):

Chris - there's a new bilingual javascript solution you can use - it's incredibly easy to use - plug n play - simply separate two strings with //, e.g. `languageone//languagetwo` and it will show the correct one for the user according to the language they've selected.

It works on larger blocks of text too using the following format:

```
[[languageone
languageone
languageone///languagetwo
languagetwo
languagetwo]]
```

[www.affiliatewebdesigners.com/product/bilingual-javascript/](http://www.affiliatewebdesigners.com/product/bilingual-javascript/)